# Use fetched data with 2 event listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, push

I'm following a guide for creating a website for web push notifications, but I'm stuck with this step, could you guys help me?

I'm getting notification data (body, icon, url etc.) from notification.php and the notification is displaying perfectly.   The problem comes when I try to pass the URL to the second event listener - for the notification click.

How can I get the URL in the first event listener and then use it in the second, without second fetch?

```
.then(function(response) {
var notif_url = response.notif_url;
```

It's working here, I want to pass notif_url to this event listener:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event, url) {
```

My serviceworker.js:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
// const analyticsPromise = pushReceivedTracking();
const pushInfoPromise = fetch('notification.php')
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
.then(function(response) {
var notif_url = response.notif_url;
console.log(notif_url);
  return self.registration.showNotification(response.notif_title, {
    "body": response.notif_body,
    "icon": response.notif_icon,
    "image": response.notif_image,
    "badge": response.notif_badge,
    "vibrate": response.notif_vibrate,
    "sound": response.notif_sound,
    "dir": response.notif_dir,
    "tag": response.notif_tag,
    "data": response.notif_data,
    "requireInteraction": true,
    "renotify": response.notif_renotify,
    "silent": false,
    // "actions": response.notif_actions,
    // "timestamp": response.notif_timestamp
  });
});

const promiseChain = Promise.all([
// analyticsPromise,
pushInfoPromise
]);

event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event, url) {
const pushInfoPromise = fetch('notification.php')
.then(function(response) {
  url = response.notif_url;
})

event.notification.close();
event.waitUntil(
clients.openWindow(url)
);
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just save notif_url as a class level variable and use it in notificationclick event?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I must get the URL from fetch('notification.php') - in the first event listener, then pass the parameter to the second listener.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your `serviceworker.js` to remove second fetch. Just need to add one more parameter in `showNotification` and you should able to get it back in event of `notificationclick`

```
// const analyticsPromise = pushReceivedTracking();
const pushInfoPromise = fetch('notification.php')
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
.then(function(response) {
var notif_url = response.notif_url;
console.log(notif_url);
  return self.registration.showNotification(response.notif_title, {
    "body": response.notif_body,
    "icon": response.notif_icon,
    "image": response.notif_image,
    "notifi_url": notif_url,
    "badge": response.notif_badge,
    "vibrate": response.notif_vibrate,
    "sound": response.notif_sound,
    "dir": response.notif_dir,
    "tag": response.notif_tag,
    "data": response.notif_data,
    "requireInteraction": true,
    "renotify": response.notif_renotify,
    "silent": false,
    // "actions": response.notif_actions,
    // "timestamp": response.notif_timestamp
  });
});

const promiseChain = Promise.all([
// analyticsPromise,
pushInfoPromise
]);

event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event, url) {
//if you already have url as separate parameter here then no need to pass it in showNotification
url = event.notifi_url
event.notification.close();
event.waitUntil(
clients.openWindow(url)
);
});
```